# Terminate program with MessageBox and Sleep()

Tags: c++

I have a class, which has 2 important functions:

1 - show a messagebox 
2 - exit the program (win32)

But if I show the MessageBox, the program does not terminate/exit.
Can someone explain to me why? 
Here is my code:

```
inline void MyClass::MessageBox()
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "This is an error!", "Error", MB_ICONSTOP | MB_OK);

    this->ExitProcess();

}

inline void MyClass::ExitProcess()
{
    while (true)
    {
        TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason this is tagged both `c#` and `c++`?

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow suggested me!

Comment: A message box is modal and will block until dismissed

Comment: Good info! Thanks! What can I do in this case ?

Comment: Press "ok" to dismiss the message box?

Comment: @AJNeufeld - That won`t work in this case, this is used for my Licensing purposes... I need to show an error message box, then terminate...

Comment: And how long do you want the error message box shown for?  Until the user has read it, and pressed "ok"?  At which point the `MessageBox(...)` call will complete, and then `this->ExitProcess()` will be called, terminating the application.  Forgive us, but isn't that what you want?  How exactly does this "not work in this case"?

Comment: I do not want to wait for the user to press "OK", I want to exit anyway after 3 seconds for example...

Comment: `stackoverflow suggested me!` That doesn't mean that you have to use the tag. Stack Overflow just suggest tags which names are similar to what you've written in the tag field. `C#` and `C++` are completely different languages.